# Reading dates in python in the far future

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to read a csv file in python that has dates even after the year 2500. The pandas .to_datetime shows dates out of bounds exception. Using a custom date parser to extract the date, month and year individually takes a lot of time. Are there any other ways to do that? Thanks for the help.

Comment: mind to share your code?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a date that does not exit in the dataframe? For instance, the 30th of february or something like that.

Comment: ok, got same error. ValueError: cannot assemble the datetimes: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 2500-02-04 00:00:00

Comment: Only 269 years ago our calendar even skipped 11 days, I wouldn't plan ahead what to do in 479 years.

Comment: you cannot use pandas' datetime64[ns] dtype, that's for sure. but to provide a helpful answer you'll have to add a specific [mre] - how does your data look like, what do you want to do with it etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known limitation of Pandas. The actual dtype is np.datetime64[ns], that is a 64 bits integer number of nanoseconds from the Unix Epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00). Pandas documentation has a chapter about [Timestamp limitation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations):

> Since pandas represents timestamps in nanosecond resolution, the time span that can be represented using a 64-bit integer is limited to approximately 584 years:
>
> ```
> In [92]: pd.Timestamp.min
> Out[92]: Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')
>
> In [93]: pd.Timestamp.max
> Out[93]: Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
> ```

Year 2500 if far after 2262, so it cannot be represented by a Pandas `Timestamp`